# Redirecting STDERR to file locks that file

Tags: perl, io

PERL Wizards, I am trying to redirect STDERR to an error file that I have opened for use if my program misbehaves.  The problem I am having is that the lines below which contain "#Help Here" somehow prevent my program from deleting empty error files.  Almost like this ties them up and prevents delete/unlink. Do you see anyway I can adjust my code to ensure that I can delete error files of 0 size?
Thank you!

```
foreach $inputFile (@inputFiles) {

    #Open input and error files for reading and writing data
    open (INFILE, '<', $inputFile) or die $!;
    $errFile = $inputFile . "-error";
    open (ERRFILE, '>', $errFile) or die $!;
    #Redirect STDERR from the console to the error log
    close (STDERR);  #Help here
    open (STDERR, '>', $errFile) or die $!;  #Help here

    #Override default line delimiter of /n with custom delimiter
    local $/ = '~~lineDelimiter~~';
        while ($inFileLine = <INFILE>)  { 

        #Create an array of fieldnames from the line being processed    
        @fieldNames = $inFileLine =~ m(<\/(.*?)>)g;
        #Create an array of data values from the line being processed
        @fieldValues =  $inFileLine =~ m(>([^<]+)<)g;

        #Populate a variable with the dbid for the line being processed
        @filter = @fieldValues[0];
        $queryDef = $session->BuildQuery("SWCR");
        $queryDef->BuildField("dbid");
        $queryFilter = $queryDef->BuildFilterOperator($CQPerlExt::CQ_BOOL_OP_AND);
        $queryFilter->BuildFilter("RecordID",$CQPerlExt::CQ_COMP_OP_EQ, \@filter);
        $queryResults = $session->BuildResultSet($queryDef);
        $queryResults->Execute();
        while ($queryResults->MoveNext() == $CQPerlExt::CQ_SUCCESS) {
            $dbid = $queryResults->GetColumnValue(1);
                                            }

        #Insert data for all fields after the SWCR (elements>=1)    
        $entity = $session->GetEntityByDbId("SWCR",$dbid);
        $entity->EditEntity("AdminModify");
        $entity->SetFieldValue($fieldNames[$_],$fieldValues[$_]) for (1 .. $#fieldNames);
        $entity->SetFieldValue("AdminModifyReason","Data from file: $inputFile was imported into this record per the MSTU/LMITS sync process.");
        #Evaluate for validation errors
        $trappedErrorValidate = $entity->Validate();
            if ($trappedErrorValidate ne "") {
                print ERRFILE "The following record has not been imported due to the error code specified below:\n\n";
                #Remove the leading newline character of the record so it prints more clearly
                $inFileLine =~ s/^\n//;
                print ERRFILE "$inFileLine\n";
                print ERRFILE "\nError Code:$trappedErrorValidate\n";
                print ERRFILE "*********************************************************************************\n";
                    $entity->Revert();
                                  } else {
                                           $trappedErrorCommit =$entity->Commit();
                                    if ($trappedErrorCommit ne "") {
                                        print ERRFILE "The following record has not been imported due to the error code specified below:\n\n";
                                        #Remove the leading newline character of the record so it prints more clearly
                                        $inFileLine =~ s/^\n//;
                                        print ERRFILE "$inFileLine\n";
                                        print ERRFILE "\nError Code:$trappedErrorCommit\n";
                                        print ERRFILE "*********************************************************************************\n";
                                                                                           } else {
                                                          $recordCount++; 
                                                                                                              }
                                      }
                              }     


    close (INFILE);
    close (ERRFILE);

    #Add amount of records imported to the import log
    open (IMPLOG, ">>", 'Import_Log.txt') or die $!; 
    print IMPLOG "$scriptStartTime: $recordCount record(s) imported into LMITS from $inputFile.\n";
    #Reset record count for each input file to use the counter
    $recordCount = 0;
    close (IMPLOG);

                                   }

# ##############################################
# ##### Process administrative items and 
# ##### Close ClearQuest session 
# ##############################################

#Mark each input file processed
foreach $inputFile (@inputFiles) {
    rename ($inputFile, $inputFile . "-processed");
                 }

#Remove blank error files
opendir(DIR, 'c:\LMITS');
@errFiles = grep /error/, readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

    foreach $errFile (@errFiles) {
        $errFileSize = -s $errFile;
        if ($errFileSize == 0) {    #Help Here
        unlink $errFile;                #Help Here
                       }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.  I made STDERR local per below:

local *STDERR;
open (STDERR, '>', $errFile) or die $!;

It's now local to the routine and releases the output file so I can unlink it later.